# Set QML theme using QQuickWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qquickwidget

I have a `QMainWindow` application that shows a `QWidget` (FormOverview) that in turns embed a `QQuickWidget`. I'm not able to set the QML theme.

I created a "qtquickcontrols2.conf" and added it to qml.qrc:

```
[Controls]
Style=Material

[Material]
Theme=Dark
Accent=Orange
Primary=White

[Material\Font]
PixelSize=50
```

here my main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 1000
    height: 1000
    visible: true

    TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: root.width

        TabButton { text: qsTr("TAB 1") }
        TabButton { text: qsTr("TAB 2") }
        TabButton { text: qsTr("TAB 3") }
        TabButton { text: qsTr("TAB 4") }
    }
}
```

I set the main.qml resource file for the `QQuickWidget` from the Designer.
Here the main.cpp code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.showMaximized();

    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.h
    FormOverview _formOverview;

MainWindow.cpp:

```
ui->tabView->addTab(&_formOverview, tr("Overview"));
```

I didn't set anything else in the code, because I thought it should find and apply the config file automatically. Instead, it renders the controls with the default theme.

Comment: Try to set path to `qtquickcontrols2.conf` as a local file using `QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_CONF` to see that custom styles work.

Comment: The problem was that file should be in the / prefix. For a mistake it was placed in a subdirectory.

Comment: You should answer the question yourself so that others know that it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-environment.html), the `QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_CONF` variable is set to ":/qtquickcontrols2.conf" by default.
Hence you have to be sure your qtquickcontrols2.conf is added to the resource file in the root prefix `/` and not in any other sub-directory.